# Laravel route() pass data

Tags: php, laravel, forms, routes, controller

I am working on a blog in Laravel 8 and i ran into a problem.

I want the user to be able to comment on a post. Do do that i store the id of the post they are commenting on.

This is my comment form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('comment.store', $post )}}">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="kommentar" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

My Controller method to store the comment:

```
    public function store(Request $request, $postid)
{
    $comment = new Comment();
    $comment->author = Auth::user()->name;
    $comment->text = $request->input('kommentar');
    $comment->post_id = $postid;
    $comment->save();

    return redirect('/post/'$postid );
}
```

And my web.php:

```
Route::resource('comment', CommentController::class);
```

I want to use the route() helper function since i want to be able to change the urls later down the line with out having to change it everywhere. I cannot figure out how to pass the form data and the post id so i can store the post that the comment belongs to.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `post id` by `hidden` field from your view and receive it from your `Controller` `store` method by using laravel `Request`.

**View**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('comment.store') }}">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{ $post_id }}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="kommentar" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Route**

```
Route::resource('comment', CommentController::class);
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $comment = new Comment();
    $comment->author = Auth::user()->name;
    $comment->text = $request->kommentar;
    $comment->post_id = $request->post_id;
    $comment->save();

    return redirect('/post/' .$request->post_id );
}
```

Comment: I copied your code and unfortunately id doesnt work for me. I have tried to dd the postid by adding  dd($request->post_id); before the save method and it is returning null.

Comment: check your `$post` variable on your `view` part. `dd($post)` value has or not ?

Comment: When i add {{dd($post)}} on my view it returns a post

Comment: so, what is your `post_id` ?

Comment: Set your `post_id` from your returned `post` to your `$post` variable.

Comment: my post_id is 21 and if i replace every post_id in my controller with 21 it works perfectly fine. So i would guess the issue is passing the post_id

Comment: It should be pass dynamically. So, tell me which variable is containing your `post_id` ?

Comment: I am sorry what do you mean by "Set your post_id from your returned post to your $post variable."

Comment: my post_id is stored  i the database under the key id

Comment: Replace your `key id` from `$post` to `key id` in the hidden field.

Comment: Ok i did that now its saying that post_id doesnt has a default value. Im thinking i might have to change the value in my view to pass just the id not the post but i could be way off

Comment: Are you sure, you correctly pass your `post id` ?

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $post}}"> thats how i pass the post

Comment: Can you check, what is the value of `$post` variable ?

Comment: dd($post) in my view i gets me this: App\Post {#1233 ▼
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "posts"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:9 [▶]
  #original: array:9 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:1 [▶]
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}

Comment: Is this `id` or `string` ? where is your `post id` ?

Comment: and when i dd($request) in my controller i get the request parameter id which is the whole post

Comment: my post id is under attributes "id" => 21 if this is what you mean

Comment: check it with `dd($request->id)`

Comment: I changed the value in the view to $post -> id and when i do dd($request->id) i get "21" but it somehow still doesnt work

Comment: what happened with this

Comment: Ok nevermind i am an idiot the key in my comment table is post_id and i changed it to id no wonder it didnt worked. I changed it to post_id and now it is working perfectly fine, Thanks a lot you really saved my night.

Comment: I am new to Stack Overflow can i mark this question as solved?

Comment: Sure, you can do this.

Comment: But how can i to that? ;-)